# SharePoint online search not returning Home Pages

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search

I cannot for the life of me work out how to return home pages within SharePoint Online search.

I have a single site collection with a number of sub sites that have a home page set as the default page, however when I create a query results source in SharePoint Online I cannot retrieve any of the homepages. They seem to be excluded?

Any ideas or thoughts to why they would be excluded?

Ideally, I just want to return all homepages for each sub-site within the site collection.

Many thanks.

Comment: It seems the following query returns pages within each sub-site but still no homepages: {searchTerms} ContentTypeId:0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF390064DEA0F50FC8C147B0B6EA0636C4A7D4003EF05CCEECF7DB419461DD6C32B9DDF603* contentclass:STS_ListItem_850

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that all your home pages are having same content type you are using in your filter. You might also use the name of content type in filter instead of id in your filter.

ContentType:"your content type name"

You also need to make sure all these pages are checked in and published to be picked up in search. If you are sure of all that, then try to reindex the whole site collection frim site settings and recheck after a while, normally it takes a couple of hours for crawl to finish and het your results. However, it sometimes take longer depending on search index load on cloud.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions of which I had already tried but unfortunately as soon as you set a page to be a homepage within a subsite it no longer gets picked up in the search results. I have never noticed this before, mainly because I have never looked for it.